# Different height between FormControl and ControlLabel in react-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I am making a label + form as follows:

```
<Form horizontal>
  <FormGroup>
    <Col xs={5} className="xxx">
      <ControlLabel>
        somekey:
      </ControlLabel>
    </Col>
    <Col xs={7} className="yyy">
      <InputGroup>
        <FormControl value="v"/>
        <InputGroup.Button>
          <Button>
            km
          </Button>
        </InputGroup.Button>
      </InputGroup>
    </Col>
  </FormGroup>
</Form>
```

However, it seems like the height of the the `ControlLabel` part is different from `InputGroup` part, after I added a `background-color` as shown in the attached image. Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I dont think you are doing anything know, this is how bootstrap works,

React bootstrap uses version bootstrap v3,

I have replicated your code example by using plain HTML, CSS and bootstrap v3 CSS.

**Open the snippet in fullscreen mode**

In the following example u can see that, there is some space below the label indicated by green background color

> Horizontal forms should never be used on small devices. i.e. You
>   should use sm instead of xs so that on small screen it becomes vertical form for good UX.

```css
.column-color {
  background-color: red;
}

.form-group-color {
  background-color: green;
}

.form-horizontal.centered .control-label {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 34px;
}

.centered-flex {
  display: flex;
}

.centered-flex .control-label {
  display: block;
  flex: 1;
  width: 140px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.centered-flex .input-group {
  flex: 5;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group form-group-color">
    <div class="col-xs-2 text-right  column-color">
      <label for="inputEmail3" class="control-label ">Email</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Test" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">km</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<br/>
<p>Horizontal forms should never be used on small devices. i.e. You should use sm instead of xs, so that on small screen it becomes vertical form</p>
<form class="form-horizontal ">
  <div class="form-group form-group-color">
    <div class=" col-sm-2 text-right  column-color">
      <label for="inputEmail3" class="control-label ">Email</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Test" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">km</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<br/>
<p>Vertically Centered using line-height method</p>
<form class="form-horizontal centered">
  <div class="form-group form-group-color">
    <div class=" col-sm-2 text-right  column-color">
      <label for="inputEmail3" class="control-label ">Email</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Test" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">km</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<p>Centered using flex</p>
<form class="form-horizontal ">
  <div class="form-group form-group-color centered-flex">

    <label for="inputEmail3" class="control-label column-color">Email</label>


    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Test" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
      <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">km</span>
    </div>

  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: But how could the two parts be aligned? As you see, `Email` is to the up-left corner of the green box.

Comment: Thanks for the update. But I think the problem is not with `xs` or `sm`. Let's assume that the screen is large enough so they will be shown horizontally. However, in this case, the `Email` is not at the center of y-axis, as you may see from your first example. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`react-bootstrap` FormGroup works by adding the `form-group` class to the DOM element. By default, `bootstrap` `form-group` doesn't mean to support adjacent, row - columns display, you will need to add extra `row` class to make it work properly.

With `bootstrap` only:

```
<div class="form-group row">...</div>
```

With `react-bootstrap`:

```
<FormGroup className="row">
</FormGroup>
```

Comment: Sry this may sound stupid but is `className` used for css setting? Does it ever help by adding `className="row"` only? Thanks!

Comment: className is used to add class to your component, you should check both the implementation of `FormGroup` on github: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/653d2a685701ebd49cd023d575c1ff425bd63186/src/FormGroup.js, as well as bootstrap document.

Comment: Actually when I tried to add `className` to make `FormGroup` exactly as said in your answer, nothing changed. Could you make sure that is working or (if possible) provide a working example? Thanks!